# PHP File Uploader leading to "Page not Found"

Tags: php, file-upload, forms

I've put together an HTML Form for a PHP File Uploader but when I use the form and attempt to upload the file I get sent to a "Page not Found" and the file never ends up where it's supposed to on my server.

Here's the Form:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><font size="2">*=Required</font></p>
  <b>Mod Name:*</b><br /><input type="text" name="modname" size="30"><br />
  <b>Author:*</b><br /><input type="text" name="author" size="30"><br />
  <b>Version:*</b><br /><input type="text" name="version" size="30"><br /><br />
  <b>Game:</b><select>
    <option value="morrowind">Morrowind</option>
    <option value="oblivion">Oblivion</option>
    <option value="skyrim">Skyrim</option>
    </select><br /><br />
 <p><b><font size="3">Dependencies:</font></b></p>
  <p>Morrowind</p>
   <input type="checkbox" value="expansion" name="tribunal" />Tribunal <br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="expansion" name="bloodmoon" />Bloodmoon <br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="mod" name="mge" />MGE <br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="mod" name="mwe" />MWE <br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="mod" name="mwse" />MWSE <br />
  <p>Oblivion</p>
   <input type="checkbox" value="expansion" name="knights" />Knights of the Nine <br />
   <input type="checkbox" value="expansion" name="isle" />Shivering Isles <br />
  <p>Skyrim</p>
   <input type="checkbox" value="expansion" name="dawnguard" />Dawnguard <br /><br />
<label for="description"><b>Description:</b></label><br />
 <textarea id="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br /><br />
<b>Uploader Name:</b><br /><input type="text" name="upname" size="30"><br /><br />
<label><b>Uploader Comments</b></label><br />
 <textarea id="uploader" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br /><br />
<b>Mirror Links:</b><br /><input type="text" name="mirror" size="50"><br /><br />
<label for="file"><b>Upload Mod:</b></label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
 <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<p><font size="2">Maximum File Size: 400MB; Only Compressed Files Accepted (.zip, .rar, .7z)</font></p>
</form>
```

and here's the upload php file:

```
    <?php
$allowedExts = array("zip, rar, 7z");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-7z-compressed"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 419430401)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 400) . " Mb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

 if (file_exists("uploads/mods/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/mods/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/mods/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Where did I mess up?

Do I need to place the .php file inside of the upload directory? Where does the form information go? Also, how do I require some of the text boxes in the form?

Thanks, I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: Page not found goes together with a web server log entry that tells you why.

Comment: Please spend a little time and format your code properly. It's a HUGE turn off to see a wall of code like that

Comment: Also `$allowedExts = array("zip, rar, 7z");
` is wrong

Comment: I apologize for the lack of formatting, I'm still new to HTML. I fixed the array line.

Comment: Try using firebug to see if it can tell you more about what's going on and where it's breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the web server logs (like suggested before) to see if they give you an idea (usually they do). Without knowing your file/directory structure, it's pretty much guesswork. I noticed the form references `upload_file.php`, then you call the second code upload php. Is it just misnamed?

Also, make sure it is in the same directory as the HTML file with your form.

If you want the `upload_file.php` file to be in a subdirectory, you can do this by changing:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to:

```
<form action="subdirectory/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I think I'm misplacing the upload_form.php file, the HTML form is being used in a wordpress page so now I need to figure out where I would place the php file so that they page can pick it up.

Comment: The HTML points to the PHP file now which is awesome. Now I need to figure out why I'm receiving "Invalid File" while trying to upload a zip file.